# Setup Node.js on Azure Bitnami server to work with a custom domain name

Tags: node.js, azure, bitnami

I just created an Azure Bitnami server. I have access to the server, I uploaded my files using Github. My server is listening on port 3000 but I can't see it there. I am not sure what to do next to use my custom domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the VM created by Bitnami Node.js tamplate, enables port 22, 80 and 443 to public. To enable public requests from 3000 port, we need to add an additional Inbound security rule of the network security group over your VM.

Sign in Azure portal (https://ms.portal.azure.com), step into the manage portal of your VM, select the **Network interface**, select the item whose public ip address is matching your VM profile, click **Network security group**, and click the link to edit it.
[image]

Then click the **Inbound security rules** in your `nsg` portal, click **Add** and input the rule settings to add a new inbound rule to your list.
[image]

After configuration finished, you can send requests against your VM via 3000 port.